# Should I precache workbox own files (copiedLibraries) for making webapp full offline

Tags: workbox

Do app require workbox libaries to be precached or cached, since it precache size increases to ~4MB from ~2MB(which is not good I guess).

> workbox-config.js

```
module.exports = {
"globDirectory":"build/",
"globPatterns":[
    "**/*.{json,ico,png,jpg,html,js,css}",
],
"globIgnores":[
    "workbox-v5.1.2/*",
    "sw.js"
],
"swDest":"build/sw.js",
"swSrc":"src/sw.js",

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to precache any resources that are fetched/imported (via `fetch` or `importScripts`) by the service worker itself. This non-requirement does not apply to [asynchronous imports](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw#avoid_async_imports).

Only exception is [Workbox Window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window).

In other words, if you're not using [Workbox Window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window), then you can safely leave the line `"workbox-v5.1.2/*"` in the `"globIgnores"`, otherwise, something like this would cache [Workbox Window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window) only:

```
module.exports = {
"globDirectory":"build/",
"globPatterns":[
    "**/*.{json,ico,png,jpg,html,js,css}",
],
"globIgnores":[
    "workbox-v5.1.2/workbox-!(window)*",
    "sw.js"
],
"swDest":"build/sw.js",
"swSrc":"src/sw.js",

}
```